# Print into file first two lines from all subfolders

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed, head

I have the following Linux command:

```
head -2 * > output.txt
```

I want to run this command for all subfolders, and get the output into the same file.

Output example:

```
path_file1:
first two lines of file1

path_file2:
first two lines of file2

..
..
..
```

Is this possible as a Linux command? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-exec` flag on the `find` command to execute `head -2`.

`find . -type f -exec head -2 {} \; > output.txt`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -sn '1,2p' * > /anotherDirectory/output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to run it and got `...is a directory` error for each one of the sub folders. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

```
output=""

for f in $(find .)
do
    output=$output"\n\n${f}:\n"$(head -2 $f)
    echo -e $output
done

echo -e $output > somefile.txt
```

It loops through all files found by "find .", adds two newlines to the output, followed by the filename and a colon, and then the head -2 command. Finally, everything is written to somefile.txt

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` in combination with `head` (`-v` prints filename)

```
find . -type f -exec head -vn2 {} \; >print.txt
```